# Is there a way to make a clone in CSS?

Tags: html, css, class

For example I have this css class:

```
.class{
   background:#FFF; 
   border:1px solid #ccc
}
```

And I have this HTML structure:

```
<ul class="list">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And I would like to use the `.class` on the `list. li` elements without adding the `class="class"` to the `<li>`'s or rewriting the whole class for the `<li>`'s.

Something like:

```
.list li{
   .class
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let some css be applied to different css selectors with comma `,`. So your example would be:

```
.class, .list li {
   background:#FFF; 
   border:1px solid #ccc
}
```

Comment: This is the standard way of doing it. However, there are frameworks as noted by **Alan**. Check out http://lesscss.org/, this is probably more of what you wanted. Unfortunately it is not part of CSS at this time.

Answer (score 1):

you know the easier way would be

```
.list li, .class {
      whatever css
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: it gets the job done =P exactly as he wants... but no as everyone mentioned, it is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately that doesn't work. Flex has that concept with

```
.myClass {
  styleName: "myStyleName";
}
```

But CSS doesn't work that way. CSS also needs nested selectors, but I wouldn't want to hang from a rope until that happened.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using plain CSS. However, CSS frameworks exist which have these functionalities.